# Windows 7 cmd wont output name of file

Tags: windows, file, menu, arguments

Why doesn't this echo the name of the file to the command prompt? This reg key puts a "Copy path" option in the explorer right click context menu in Windows 7. And runs that command.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy path]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy path\command]
@="cmd echo \"%1\""
```

The cmd prompt shows up but the name of the file is not displayed. Why?

Comment: You want `cmd /k` rather than just `cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd's natural behavior is to terminate after it runs. Use /k argument to keep the prompt open.